# Python perform FFT on wave data for a 25fps animation

Tags: python, animation, fft, wave, spectrum

I am doing a project where I want to use the data of a .wav file to drive animation. The problems I am facing are mainly due to the fact that the animation is 25fps and I have 44100 samples per second in the .wav file, so I've broken down apart to 44100/25 samples. Working with the amplitude is fine and I created an initial test to try it out and it worked. This is the code

```
import wave
import struct

wav = wave.open('test.wav', 'rb')

rate = 44100
nframes = wav.getnframes()

data = wav.readframes(-1)

wav.close()

data_c = [data[offset::2] for offset in range(2)]

ch1 = struct.unpack('%ih' % nframes, data_c[0])
ch2 = struct.unpack('%ih' % nframes, data_c[1])

kf = []

for i in range(0, len(ch2), 44100/25):
    cur1 = 0
    cur2 = 0
    for j in range(i, i+44100/25):
        cur1+=ch2[j]
        cur2+=ch1[j]
    cur = (cur1+cur2) / 44100. / 25. / 2.
    kf.append(cur)

min_v = min(kf)
max_v = max(kf)
if abs(max_v) > abs(min_v):
        kf = [float(i)/max_v for i in kf]
else:
        kf = [float(i)/min_v for i in kf]
```

Now I want to get the spectrum for each separate keyframe as I do for the amplitude, but I am struggling to think of a way to do it. I can get the spectrum for the whole file using FFT, but that's not I want, because ideally I would like to have different movements of the objects in accordance to different frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at scipy wavfile. It'll turn the wave file into a numpy array. Numpy also has fft functions. Scipy/matplotlib has a spectrogram plot for the entire spectrogram.

```
from scipy.io import wavfile

sample_rate, data = wavfile.read(filename)
```

Then you have to get your timing of how you want to read the data. Matplotlib has animation tools that will call a function at a given interval. The other way of doing it is to use PyAudio. If you use pyaudio you can listen to the data while it is displayed.

Next run the data through the FFT. Store the FFT values in a spectrogram array and use matplotlib imshow to display the spectrogram array. You will probably have to rotate the array in some fashion when you display the spectrogram.

From personal experience be careful of python threads. Threading works for I/O, but for calculations the thread can just dominate the whole application slowing everything down. Also GUI elements (like plotting) don't really work in threads. Use matplotlibs animation tools for the plotting.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I've been using numpy arrays and performing FFTs on them without hitch, but my problem is getting the timing right. As you can see, I've split the timing in a 25 fps manner for the amplitude, but I am struggling to do FFT on these chunks of 1764 samples. I've tried running FFT on them, but then I don't know how to interpret the output of that in a spectrum analysis.